# Design suggestion for handling large mailboxes using java mail api (IMAP)

Tags: java, email, imap, fetch

We use java mail api with imap and fetch messages of folders containing millions of messages. There are some rules and limitiations:

*We do not have always open connections to mail server and therefore we can not add listeners.*

*The messages will be stored in a local database with all properties, subject, body, receive date, from etc.*

*Can not use multiple threads*

To keep the performance at acceptable levels and prevent out of memory crashes, I am planning:

1.During inital fetch, where all messages have to be fetched, store only the message headers and bypass body and attachments. Getting the body and attachment of a message will be done when requested by the client. The initialization can take hours, it is not a problem.

2.When fetching all messages at start, use a appropriate fetch profile to make it faster, but process in blocks, for example:

```
Message m1[] = f.getMessages(1, 10000);
f.fetch(m1, fp);
//process m1 array

Message m2[] = f.getMessages(10001, 20000);
f.fetch(m2, fp);
//process m2 array
```

instead of

```
Message m_all[] = f.getMessages(1, NUMALLMESSAGES);
f.fetch(m_all, fp);
//process m_all array, may throw out of memory errors
```

3.And after we have all the messages, store the UID of recent message in the DB and on the next fetch perform:

```
f.getMessagesByUID(LASTUIDREADFROMDB, UIDMAX)
```

Do you have additional suggestions, or see any points we have to care of (memory, performance)

Comment: Do you care about flags?  Do you care about deleted messages?

Comment: Yes i care about both, but i think there is no option other than comparing full folder with the db, here again i have to work in gropus. But the performance will degrade. Checking flags or deleted messages can be designed depending on user options, for example fetch only new mails or synch full messages. Any idea or suggestion well appreciated.